# Interpretation 0f percentile

Tags: percentile

How do we interpret the meaning of a percentile?

What I have learned from books is as follows: "If a score is the 40th percentile, this means that it is larger than 40% of the distribution, while the other 60% of scores are greater than or equal to the score."

My question is when that specific score equals to the previous score, shouldn't we say 40% of the distribution is "less or equal" to that score, instead of "less than" that score?

For example, say there are 500 students, and they are scored from 0 to 100. Say student A gets a score 80 and he is in 85th percentile, which traditionally means 85 percent student is less than his score and 15% is greater or equal to his score. In a specific case let 250 higher scorer students get all equal to a score of 80. Then student A is not higher than 85%. Or his score is not higher than the other student who also get 80. Is he?

Comment: Your question has countless errors. Please look over what you've written.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. but, this is all i find about the interpretation of percentile. can you please clarify a bit, which part is error?

Comment: Look at your first sentence in quotation marks. You move from the $p$-th percentile to the 40th percentile. The $p$ should be a 40, and the 70 should be a 60 (or the 40 should be a 30).

Comment: In a PG Wodehouse novel, Bertram Wooster laments, ".. this proves the well-known fact that half the world does not know what the rest of the three quarters is doing"

Comment: sorry, i have corrected. thank you both

Comment: I am actually struggling with this thing too much, sorry for my carelessness.